# Which is the java version that does not allow the malware to to automatically install from a webpage?

Tags: java, security, applet, version, malware

I have seen that if you have a 'new' version of java in your browser, then you are not in danger of having a malware capable of installing into your computer automatically from seeing a web page, by using a java ... flaw.

Can you please tell me which is the java 'safe' version, that does not allow the malware to automatically install on computer?

(I really need to know if I was exposed to infection yesterday... is java 6 a 'good' choice)

The thing is that I want to be sure that I am 'safe'.

Comment: Nothing is 100% secure (see above) but keeping update to date with the latest Java usually helps the best (with the exception of new 0-day bugs being introduced)

Comment: You should just disable java in the browser unless you explicitly need it.  For most users it is unnecessary now.

Comment: If you are trying to clean yourself of a virus, updating java after the fact will not remove the virus but _may_ prevent it from happening again.

Comment: the thing is that I want to be sure that I am 'safe'...therefore, I am interested in the specific version....

Comment: This question would be a perfect fit for the old "Too Localized" close reason... any answer will only be valid until a newer version of Java comes out, at which point any answers would be outdated.  Voted to close.

Comment: To avoid the question being too localized, the comment *"the thing is that I want to be sure that I am 'safe'"*  should be part of the question.  Then I think we can make the answer that I did..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to be sure that I am 'safe'

The only way to be sure you are safe from malware from Java exploits is to uninstall it completely.  The best that can be said of the latest, most secure Java version is that it has no ***known*** security bugs.

Java has reached 1.7, so just about any 1.6 version should be considered unsafe.

> the thing is that I have used yahoo and there seems to be a problem [Malicious advertisements served via Yahoo](http://blog.fox-it.com/2014/01/03/malicious-advertisements-served-via-yahoo/)

That page notes:

> The investigation showed that the earliest signs of infection were at **December 30, 2013.** Other reports suggest it might have started even earlier.

Now let us look at [Release Dates for Java 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6_.28December_11.2C_2006.29).  The last **publicly available** Java 6 version is:

```
Java SE 6 Update 45[76]     2013-04-16  42 security fixes;[77] other changes;[76] final public update[78]
```

Or April 16th, last year.  Some 8 months *before* that security alert.

Like I have been saying.  Every publicly available version of Java 6 should be considered suspect. 
Every - *single - **one.***

*You should run a Malware checker on your machine.*

But your answers & comments indicate to me something more.  You don't really need to run Java applets in the browser, and probably do not need it for any other reason, so also ***uninstall Java completely.***

And I do mean **uninstall it,** I do not mean not disable it, I do not mean not keep it up to date.  You do not seem to need it on your PC, so don't take the risk.

Comment: What do you actually use Java in the browser for?  If there is nothing you can immediately name, I would recommend uninstalling it.

Comment: @RacerNerd  Too bad you got down-voted.  But I will leave this answer here no matter how many down-votes it gets.  I have a vast experience with applets, and feel the OP is best off uninstalling it unless they have a clearly defined need.  As an aside, I disagree that it is 'often a target for hackers', but the OP is asking for certainty, so feel I need to be plain that it can never be truly trusted 100%.

Comment: if 1.7 is better, can you please tell me which update version is already fine? Thanks....

Comment: *"is already fine?"*  100% **certain** fine, or no **known** bugs?  BTW - please answer my question.  It is designed to help you.  What do you use Java for?

Comment: the thing is that I have used yahoo and there seems to be a problem - http://blog.fox-it.com/2014/01/03/malicious-advertisements-served-via-yahoo/

Comment: Yes, be worried.  Read the update to my answer very carefully.

Comment: You're welcome.  Hope it all goes well for you with the malware checks.

Answer (score 2):

Java is actually one of the most secure languages since it has a built-in security manager that can be used to sandbox applications and does a lot of built-in array out of bounds checks to prevent things like buffer overruns.

However, there have been a lot of problems in recent years regarding the security in Java **applets**.  These are Java programs that can be run from a webbrowser.  Applets have an even stricter sandbox to prevent the applet (or the website) from accessing your filesystem etc but there have been bugs found that can allow malicious code to escape the sandbox.  These bugs are patched as quickly as possible so it is important to update Java (and keep up to date) on a regular basis.

If you don't need to run applets in your browser, the best thing to do to avoid these problems is to disable applets in your browser.  [This link can be used to learn how to disable applets in your browser of choice](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/08/30/how-turn-off-java-browser/)

Comment: can you please tell me which is the java version affected by this - this is what interests me the most right now...

Comment: I'm not sure which problem you are affected by so I will say all but the latest version is affected.  The current version of Java is 7u45 so if you don't have that, update

Comment: And if you listen to my post and disable applets in your browser, you shouldn't be vulnerable to these exploits.

Comment: To "listen" to your post she might need a Java Applet to change text to speech and might get malware from one of the quickly patched holes that's still left.